# Data after (&) character is not getting saved in db using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, froala

I have integrated **froala editor**. When I fetch the value of div, the data after `&nbsp;` does not get saved in my db.

Below is the value of my div

`Hello, Froala inline!<br>line 2<br>line 3&nbsp; and url - <a href="http://google">http://google</a>.com`

Data saved in db:  `Hello, Froala inline!<br>line 2<br>line 3`

How do I make sure entire data is saved? Do I need to do domething at the froala editor end or at php end?

I think this happens with `'` and `&` , if these special characters are there, PHP deletes the text beyond this. What is the solution?

Comment: you realize what `>` blockquotes are for, right? "Text", not personal highlighting.

Comment: I am sorry, i did not realized while typing, my mistake

Answer (score 0):

In php try this:

```
$dataToDatabase = mysqli_real_escape_string('Hello, Froala inline!<br>line 2<br>line 3&nbsp; and url - <a href="http://google">http://google</a>.com');
```

Answer (score 0):

send value in

> encodeURIComponent();

and save in php

> mysqli_real_escape_string()